# How to connect rooms from Amadeus Hotel services

Tags: amadeus

So i have database where i store hotels and rooms to that hotels.
Now we are connecting Amadeus Hotel services with our database. There is no problem to connect hotel from Amadeus with our hotel. There is property code and Amadeus id.

The problem is with rooms. We can't find any tutorial about connecting rates (rooms) that are returned from MultiSingleAvailability with our rooms. We have in Amadeus response room_type, room_type_code, rate_plan_code but all of those codes can change as hotel is updating for example property code or doing other things. We need this connection as data that is returned about rooms is very poor and low quality.

Is there any safe way to connect rates with our rooms ?

Answer (score 1):

room_type is returned to us from the hotel providers and corresponds to the type of the room, the quality varies depending on the provider behind.

Something that might help is the following field:

```
   "typeEstimated": {
      "category": "ACCESSIBLE_ROOM",
      "beds": 1,
      "bedType": "QUEEN"
    },
```

Here we are attempting to extract better information about the room by combining the room code with parsing the room description. Of course, we cannot guarantee that this information is 100% accurate.

rateCode: A rate code comes from the provider but is represented in an Amadeus format. It cannot be used to identify a room. In fact, the same room can be offered using multiple rate codes.

For example: RAC is the public rate offered to everyone, while the hotel could for example offer a discounted price for government workers with the code GOV. A hotel offer is thus a combination of a room type and a rate code.

How are you building your database? What identifiers are you using? Where did you get them from?